# Twitter-Bootstrap 3 Grid Layout Overlapping

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css-float, overlay, grid-layout

I'm playing around with the new Bootstrap 3.0

Here's what I almost want :

http://bootply.com/vincentmorneau/79018

The last panel should be col-xs-12 so it takes 100% width. Then I'd have my panels on 4 separate rows with the 3rd row being only half full. I set it to col-xs-11 for demo purposes.

Here's what happen when I put the last panel to col-xs-12 :

http://bootply.com/vincentmorneau/79036

It's eating all my other panels. Why?

Comment: On another note, if you wrap your `<div class='row'></div>` with a `container` class. It will fix the horizontal scroll bar. :)

Answer (score 2):

You have to clear before your col-xs-12 container. See updated version: http://bootply.com/79725

P.S. You shouldn't use inline CSS but instead create a class .clear or something like that.